# Does snowflake support positive lookbehind in a regex?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to use a positive lookbehind as part of my `regexp_substr` expression.

I have the below:

```
regexp_substr(My_Data, '(?<=id:).*(?=;)', 1, 1)
```

which gives me the below error:

> Invalid regular expression: '(?<=id:).*(?=;)', no argument for repetition operator: ?

I'm trying to split key value pairs where I have

> id:1234;

Comment: While Snowflake regexp functions don't support non-capturing groups, lookaheads, and lookbehinds, Snowflake supports JavaScript and it supports all of these. You can write a JavaScript UDF to get non-capturing groups or lookarounds. I've also written a library of JavaScript UDFs that approximate the syntax of the Snowflake regexp functions as closely as possible that support these capabilities: https://snowflake.pavlik.us/index.php/2020/11/20/regex-non-capturing-groups-and-lookarounds-in-snowflake/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look-behind is not supported in Snowflake's regexp.

However, you can use regular regexp groups for what you're trying to achieve:

```
select regexp_substr('Something,id=12345;Somethng', 'id=([^;]+);',1, 1, 'e');
-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
 REGEXP_SUBSTR('SOMETHING,ID=12345;SOMETHNG', 'ID=([^;]+);',1, 1, 'E') |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
 12345                                                                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Note the `'e'` argument for extraction, see [the documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions-regexp.html#label-regexp-parameters-argument).